# How to filter or select rows that contain only dates in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas data frame, with a column as follows:

```
df["Date"]
2015-04-11 00:00:00
2015-03-11 00:00:00
NaN
2014-11-15 00:00:00
its not available
2017-01-27 00:00:00
2016-05-21 00:00:00
was not detected
2015-09-16 00:00:00
incomplete
...
```

I would like to filter out only those rows that contain the dates.

```
df["Date"]
2015-04-11 00:00:00
2015-03-11 00:00:00
2014-11-15 00:00:00
2017-01-27 00:00:00
2016-05-21 00:00:00
2015-09-16 00:00:00
....
```

Please let me know if there is a way to filter the dates. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `to_datetime` + `errors='coerce'` with `notna`

```
df=df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='coerce').notna()].copy()
df

Out[925]: 
                  Date
0  2015-04-11 00:00:00
1  2015-03-11 00:00:00
3  2014-11-15 00:00:00
5  2017-01-27 00:00:00
6  2016-05-21 00:00:00
8  2015-09-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: ++ for also adding the copy() to avoid possible SettingWithCopyWarning later.

Comment: And how do you do the exact opposite - keeping the rows that do not contain the date?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming because they are mixed dates and strings that the column is full of object and not datetime datatype. Are there no actual times in your dataframe? If not (meaning they are all `00:00:00`) you can do a partial string search for the 0's.

`df[df['Date'].str.contains('00:00:00')]`